# PHP or javascript to auto fill text box(s) select and submit the form data for url provided

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Post loading the URL: http://example.com/demo/website/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=product, i have a form. This form has

- Text Box
- Checkbox
- Submit Button

What i need is, i need to browse the URL, and Enter a product name value "Product1" in the Text box and then put a "Check" in the Checkbox and then Click on submit button.

I need the same activity to repeat or apply to all the 4000 products at the same time.

**Form looks like:**

```
<form name="post" action="post.php" method="post" id="post" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="post_title" size="30" value="" id="title" spellcheck="true" autocomplete="off">
<input value="8" type="checkbox" name="tax_input[product_cat][]" id="in-product_cat-8">
<input type="submit" name="publish" id="publish" class="button button-primary button-large" value="Publish">
</form>
```

Example:
1. After the url loads
2. Type "Product1" automatically in the Textbox
3. Put a check to the Checkbox
4. Click Submit

This example is for one single product, if i have to do the same for next 4000 products, i think i need a array solution to execute **different input values** to **different products** but all at **same time**. i am little confused to start with.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Have you looked up how to submit a form with JavaScript?  What attempt have you made?  Also, it's not really clear why you even need to do this.  If the page is loaded from your site, and the form is submitted to your site... Then you already *have* the information you need when the page originally loads.  Why the extra step?

Comment: @David say i have array of data for that i should be adding all the time and i should click submit so instead of that i need a startup code am confused how to start a code which can pass a n number of value and submit to on each fill and selection

Comment: @ShaikAsif: I realize there's a language barrier here, but I'm afraid that comment made very little sense and didn't clarify *anything*.  Can you elaborate with an example?

Comment: @David i have edited my question, let me know if it is clear this time ?

Comment: If I understand you well, you want to add lets say 400 products to your database using the form provided, and you want to do it on your own site or the site which you have full access to it. am I right?

Comment: @EhsanT yes its my site i have admin access to perform this activity sry for late reply

Comment: So, my question is if it's a one time operation, why don't you use `php` and insert the records directly to the DB?

Comment: @EhsanT am not sure how to do this to be more clear am assuming that this can be done in real scenario my website is a woocommerce built on wordpress and i have zero clue to startup with php provided some thing can be helpful for me to understand the process

Comment: OK, depending on your knowledge on `php` and `jquery` you either have to do it the easy way, using `php` and load your data in a `php array` and then run an `insert query` on your `database` to insert them directly to the `DB`, or your can do it the hard way, using `jQuery` loading your data to a `javascript array` and post them using `jQuery.post()` to your server.

Comment: @EhsanT if the php code can be runned but the data base of the wordpress cannot be viewed as they are hosted on a client servers provider server and if you help me out on the above any thing as you mentioned by using php or javascript i can figure it out to run php by taking permission or by jquery form my local to server

Comment: as I mentioned before, it totally depends on you. `php` is more reliable. you do not need direct access to the `database server` and if your `php script` has access to it, it's enough. but you have to be aware of the `table structure` and `database design` of your tables when inserting data to it manually. If you have these information I say choose `php` otherwise I say go with `jQuery` and `ajax`. you can easily find many sample codes searching for `jQuery.post()`. so please first give it a try.